Beaver's Triple Generation: Offline Phase
I know that the Beaver's triple generation is used to reduce the complexity in the online phase during multiplication gate.
However, how are the triples generated during offline place?
Are there multiple ways of generating triples (a,b,c) in the offline phase?
What will be the complexity of generating such triples for one multiplication gate?
